# ODE in matlab -differential equations

Tags: matlab, mathematical-modeling

I need help with this excercise : Find $k$(speed constant )
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=k(a-x)^2)$$  with data , $$t[min]=[0, 2.5, 5.6 ,9.6 ,14.6, 21.5, 32.5, 52.2]$$ ;

$(a-x)$ (mol/l) = [$0.0050$ (**if x=0**), $0.0045$ , $0.0040,0.0035,0.0030,0.0025,0.0020,0.0015]$

I´ve tried next steps:

Command W. :

$$t=[0 , 2.5,  5.6 , 9.6 , 14.6,  21.5 , 32.5 , 52.2];$$

$$x=[0:0.0005:0.0035];$$

$$a=0.0050;$$

$$c=a-x;$$

Editor ( my skript):

function $$dx=f(t,x)$$

$$dx=k*.((a-x).^2)$$

$$end   + Run$$

Command W. :

$$tspan=0:0.0005:0.0035;$$

$$[x,t]=ode45(f,[0:0.0005:0.0035],0)$$

I don´t know how to find k

Comment: Hi Helena. Can you please tell us about the things you have tried? Click "Edit" above. If you haven't tried anything, this question perhaps doesn't belong here. Also we suggest you review this material: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959

Answer (score 0):

Your ODE is separable and has as solution

$$
x(t) = \frac{a k t -1 + a c_0}{k t + c_0}
$$

then one way to obtain the best fit to $k$ is by solving the following minimization problem

$$
\min_{k,c_0}\sum_{j=1}^n(a-x(t_j)-\delta_j)^2
$$

with

$$
\cases{
a = 0.0050\\
n = 8\\
t_j = \{0,2.5,5.6,9.6,14.6,21.5,32.5,52.2\}\\
\delta_j=\{0.0050,0.0045,0.0040,0.0035,0.0030,0.0025,0.0020,0.0015\}
}
$$

NOTE

If $x(0) = 0$ then

$$
x(t) = \frac{a^2k t}{a k t+1}
$$

and now the minimization reads

$$
\min_{k}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(a-\frac{a^2k t_j}{a k t_j+1}-\delta_j\right)^2
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have problem with correct comands in matlab . I solved the example by hand on paper and after integration : $$k=x/a*t*(a-x) $$ only for conditions that t=0 and x=0

Comment: Can you please send me a script or comands from matlab on mail : hvesteg63@gmail.com  for a better understanding .